# sonarQube Findbug error and ##[error]java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not execute Findbugs

Tags: azure, scala, sonarqube, databricks, sonarqube-scan

I am really struggling from months. We are trying to scan SCALA code with SonarQube in Azure Devops which is in Databricks. We were getting around 30 error. But now we work around our self and  still getting 7-6 errors. Also our source code is fully complied in databricks itself.

still getting few errors : Please help us to rectify this issue . really appreciate.
we are using findbug version- 4.0.3 , which i know is quite old but admin team won't update this as its a large organization . let me know what i m missing.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me after adding :

```
sonar.java.binaries=[YOUR_BUILD_DIR] (target/classes)
```

Refer this Github  link for more information :

https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-findbugs/issues/49

Comment: what will come in build directory ? YOUR_BUILD_DIR
because i m getting same errors

Comment: YOUR_BUILD_DIR should be your workspace.

Comment: is it like for scala we shd have minimum that version or something of findbug ?

Comment: sonar.java.binaries=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)(target/classes)
writing like this